# How to dynamically change the id of a HTML button element within a XSL file?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have a button with an id property that I want to make its value to change dynamically. I use two javascript functions through 'setId' and 'getId' functions that I have defined. Indeed the id property of current button which is set (See 'setId' function below) must be the same as the one that is given as parameter to a javascript code (See the call of 'getId' function from 'toggle' below).

The snippet below is an example of a static html behaviour,

```
<td align="right">KO<input id="1" type="button"  
value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggle('tb','1');"/></td>
```

To make it dynamic, I use 'setId' and 'getId' functions below

```
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript">

var setId = (function () {
return function(element) {
if (!element.id) {
    element.id+ = 1;
    }
  };
}());

var getId = (function () {
 return function(element) {
return element.id;
};
 }());

</script>
</head>
```

To make it change progressively, I call them as follows within the 'body' html element

```
<td align="right">KO<input id="setId(this);" type="button"  
value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggle('tb',getId(this));"/></td>
```

Nevertheless, It seems that the id of the button ('input') does not change as expected. Indeed, click event on whatever button always refers to the first button while I want it to refer to the current. Please how could I change javascript functions to realize what I want to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well with the Javascript code `toggle('tb','getId(this);');` you are calling a function named `toogle` with two string arguments given literally, one is the string `tb`, the other the string `getId(this);`. If you want to call the function `getId` and pass its result to the function `toggle` use

```
onclick="toggle('tb',getId(this));"
```

Comment: the call js function is right now but all click actions on buttons always refer to the first button. Please how could I change my js to make it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the id at xsl transforming or you need to write a javascript, that remove the old button and add new button with the new id.

I don't know any other way to change dynamicaly the id of an html element.

Comment: It's a quite bit that I am searching. Thanks